# Need help moving div to top so that it is cross-browser compatible

Tags: css, position, css-position

I'm looking at a review system for my site, and currently the implementation has it shown at the very bottom of the page (please see the url: http://tinyurl.com/mlvq48w)

I think DIV.yotpo.reviews.yoNoPad is what encompasses the whole thing.

Can someone tell me how to move that up to the top using css so that it will be cross-browser compatible?

I'm not too concerned about obscure or very old browsers.

Comment: CSS is not the solution.  You're also asking us to fix your website (not a specific programming problem).  Ask your developer to modify your website.

Comment: Code please. Break your problem down in pieces and post only the problem part. No one wants to look at the whole website and find the issue for you and then fix it for you.

Comment: CSS is the solution.  And even though I submitted an answer I mostly agree with the previous statements.

Comment: Also you shouldn't use shortened urls - they could go anywhere and a lot of people won't bother clicking on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `clear: both;` from `.yoyo`.  This is the same DIV you mentioned.

**Or**

Add `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: block;` as *Keith* mentioned below.

Comment: you can also add display:inline-block; which will shoot it to the top too

Comment: @Keith _peeescheewwww_ (imitating the noise it made when it shot up!)

Comment: Thank you.  The css is hosted on another domain, so I used the element css (inline-block), and yes, I heard the same sound as it shot up to the top.  Thank you!